# How to link an excel document to lyx

Tags: lyx

I want to insert tables into lyx. And I think the best way is to link the excel document where  the tables are stored to the lyx file. I have installed gnumeric and inserted the excel as external material to lyx. However, lyx reports can not find the approriate converter. So my question is how to add the converter to lyx. The add converter button in preference is grey.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX, Yan! To the close-voters: Please comment on your decision as this is the OPs first post.

Comment: There are a few different ways to do this. See examples/spreadsheet.lyx for several ways. They all worked for me on Ubuntu last time I checked. You might just need to go to Tools > Reconfigure and then restart LyX.